# WPF DataBinding not updating using BooleanToVisibilityConverter

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to hide an element based on a bool.  I use a button in this example, but it doesn't work no matter what element type I use.

Here is the XAMl that contains the binding.

```
<Button
    Command="local:CustomCommands.Toggle"
    Content="Toggle"
    Visibility="{Binding Show, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
```

Here is the view model I am binding to.

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool show = true;

        public bool Show
        {
            get
            {
                return show;
            }
            set
            {
                value = show;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Show)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've debugged and see the property changing, but nothign updates on the view.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your setter "value=show" you have to exchange these parameters. (show = value;)  I would like to see your converter too. Btw if i were you, i would implement the ICommand in the viewmodel part.

Comment: You're right, oops!  Thanks!